# Creating a thick-to-slim border/box-shadow in css

Tags: css

How would I achieve the following as seen in the image below, in the best way as possible? I want a thick top border, but as it goes down I want the sides to become thinner and just "mend" (if that's right expression) into the black block.

[image: block with a thick top edge but it becomes thinner as it goes down]

This is my CSS code for the black block:

```
.containerMain {
    background: #000;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

Comment: There is no way you can do this with a single CSS property or tag, you will need a workaround to achieve your goal. The best way -as you requested- would be [using a gradient CSS border](https://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/), good luck.

Comment: Best way is to make a new block (using ::before or ::after) and give that the desired size and/or perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo-element to position an upside-down trapezoid behind your element.

Look [here](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) for a trapezoid shape example.

```css
body { padding: 30px; }

.containerMain {
  background: black;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}

.containerMain:after {
  content: '';
  border-radius: inherit;
  margin: -20px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;

  /* upside-down red trapezoid props */
  border-top-width: 150px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: red;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerMain"></div>
```

Comment: I guess that works. Will have to modify a bit but thanks for sharing your method!

Comment: No problem, hope it helped